# Oracle DB connection with PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I want to connect PHP with oracle DB. I have written the following code

```
<?php
$db_user='system';
$db_pass='19941992';
$db_name="webproj";

        $connection = oci_connect($db_name,$db_pass,'localhost/ORCL');
        if (!$connection) { 
    echo "Couldn't make a connection!"; 
    exit; 
    } 

?>
```

But its showing an error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

NB. I have installed php_oci8.dll . How can i solve this?

Comment: Does `php_info()` confirm it is active?

Comment: Did you add your dll to php.ini? is it correct php.ini? did you restart server?

Comment: Yes , I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use oci8 module, beside enabling php_oci8.dll you need to have installed an Oracle Client.
You can try Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client or Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

Download from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
I suggest version 10.2.0.5, Instant Client Package - Basic Lite

Comment: Oracle Express 10g is installed in my machine. Do i need to install Oracle instant client afterwards?

Comment: run php from command line and check if there are any errors or run `php -m` to see loaded modules

Comment: enabling mod_fcgid module stops starting apache server. Note that i have 64 bit Windows, But mod_fcgit is 32 bit. Where i can get a 64 bit module?